# Adding items to empty pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to dynamically extend an empty pandas DataFrame in the following way:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
indices=['A','B','C']
colums=['C1','C2','C3']
for colum in colums:
    for index in indices:
        #df[index,column] = anyValue
```

Where both indices and colums can have arbitrary sizes which are not known in advance, i.e. I cannot create a DataFrame with the correct size in advance.

Which pandas function can I use for

```
#df[index,column] = anyValue
```

?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df.loc[0,1] = 10
df.loc[2,8] = 100
print(df)
      1      8
0  10.0    NaN
2   NaN  100.0
```

Faster solution with [`DataFrame.set_value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
indices = ['A', 'B', 'C']
columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
for column in columns:
    for index in indices:
       df.set_value(index, column, 1)

print(df)
    C1   C2   C3
A  1.0  1.0  1.0
B  1.0  1.0  1.0
C  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Yes, that would be possible - but I need the indices and the column strings. Is there any variation of loc such that the resulting df would contain the indices 'A','B' etc and the column names 'C1','C2' ?

Answer (score 2):

`loc` works very well, but...
For single assignments use `at`

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
indices = ['A', 'B', 'C']
columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
for column in columns:
    for index in indices:
        df.at[index, column] = 1

df
```

[image]

---

## `.at` vs `.loc` vs `.set_value` timing

[image]

Comment: Can you add timings for set_value?

Comment: One little complaint, though: The order of column and index seems to be wrong in df.at. it should be df.at[index,column] - otherwise: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1934212 fixed